# Holomorphic vector bundle on Complex Compact Manifold

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a complex compact manifold.

When does $M$ admit one holomorphic vector bundle?

What is the obstruction for $M$ to admit such a holomorphic  vector bundle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont know much about this, but seems like the tangent and the cotangent bundle are always holomorphic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_vector_bundle

Comment: Hi Andrea Marino. I don't know much about that either. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion on the subject.